# undefined when updating svelte store with an array of objects

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-3, svelte-store

I'm trying to update svelte store with an array of users fetched from server:

```
  const fetchUsers = async () => {
    const resp = await fetch(baseUrl + "/users/");
    if (!resp.ok) {
      throw new Error(`HTTP error ${resp.status}`);
      console.log(Error);
    } else {
      users = await resp.json();
      $UsersStore.update((currentState) => {
      return [...currentState, users];
    });
      console.log("users are:", users);
      console.log("$UsersStore is:", $UsersStore);
    }
  };
```

The store is defined as follows:

```
import {writable} from 'svelte/store';

const UsersStore = writable ([]);

export default UsersStore;
```

The console log values are like:

```
users are: (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
$UserStore is: [Array(4)]
```

So when I iterate over users

```
{#each $UersStore as user}
    <div> {user.username} </div>
{/each}
```

I get `undefined`.

I also tried things like

```
UsersStore.update((currentState) => {
        return [currentState.push(users)];
```

But that did not work either.

I'm wondering how can I fix this?

Comment: What does `users[0]` look like?

Comment: It looks like `{id: 42, username: 'bob'}`

Answer (score 0):

Well, basically I needed to concatenate the users array to the existing store:

```
  UsersStore.update((us) => {
    return us.concat(users);
  });
```

I'm not sure its the idiomatic way to update the svelte store but it works nonetheless.

Hopefully this help others too, because I had not seen any such example involving setting fetched json data to store in existing tutorials.